# Editing multiple properties in userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform with 25 Option Buttons  (OptionButton1, OptionButton2, etc..)  I want to populate the captions of each of these buttons with information from the spreadsheet.  I'm not sure of the best code to get this done.

```
For x = 1 to 25
    OptionButton & x & .caption = range("a" & x)
Next x
```

Obviously that won't work but that's kind of what I want it to do.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim x As Byte
    'change Sheet1 to suit
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For x = 1 To 25
            Me.Controls("OptionButton" & x).Caption = .Range("A" & x)
        Next x
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You are the World's Greatest simoco!!  Thank you.